# How to use parameterized queries in SqlDataSource.SelectCommand in code behind?

Tags: c#, parameterized-query

I have a code behind method that uses SqlDataSource object to retrieve data from database, then is used as a data source for my grid view to display the records. I need to conditionally add another condition to my WHERE clause of my SelectCommand query, and need to pass the data to the query through parameters. How do I do this?

```
SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();

sds.SelectCommand = "Select CustomerName, LoanNumber, LoanDate FROM Loan WHERE IsActive = 1 ";

if (filterRecord != "All") {   // DDL filter on page, all records by default
    sds.SelectCommand += "AND LoanType = ??";   //this is where I need to parameterize my query
}
```

I thought something like

```
if (filterRecord != "All") {  
    sds.SelectCommand += "AND LoanType = @LoanType";
    sds.SelectParameters.Add("@LoanType", "Mortgage");
}
```

But that does not appear to work.

Comment: `But that does not appear to work.`  What doesn't work?  Is there an exception?

Comment: It says "Must declare scalar variable "@LoanType".

Comment: Did you use the `LoanType = ??` or the `LoanType = @LoanType`?

Comment: I am using LoanType = @LoanType. The first example was just suggesting I do not know what to put there

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sds.SelectParameters.AddWithValue`?

Comment: I don't see the option for AddWithValue. Only Add

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SqlDataSource class.  They must not have that option, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise switching to an SqlCommand object To define your query and reading the records with an SqlDataReader object. You are able to add parameters to your query using something similar to following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", value);
```

Afterwards, you can bind the SqlDataReader to the grid view as you normally would, by declaring it as the data source.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I ended up doing. I never could figure out how to add parameters to the SqlDataSource

Answer (score 0):

I did not considered that you are using the Datasource Object:

Add a ASP parameter to the SQL data source:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="LoanType" Type="String" DefaultValue="default" />
```

Change the select command to:

```
"Select CustomerName, LoanNumber, LoanDate FROM Loan WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (@LoanType="default" or LoanType =@LoanType)"
```

Then in your code behind do this:

```
if (filterRecord != "All") {  
    sds.SelectParameters("LoanType").DefaultValue="Mortgage"
}
```

**Description:**
You need to define the sql parameter in the ASP webform before editing in the code behind. I defined a parameter with a dummy value "default". So if in the  you do not change the parameter in code behind the parameter  @LoanType is equal to "default" string and the @LoanType="default" will returns true for all rows and it will not consider the LoanType =@LoanType. 
However, If you change the parameter in code behind the @LoanType="default" returns false and it will check LoanType=@LoanType for each row which will result in what you want!

**My OLD Answer:**
This is good when you do not use the sql data source and you are using your sql command

```
if (filterRecord != "All") {  
    SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter();
    Parameter.ParameterName = "@LoanType";
    Parameter.SourceColumn = "LoanType";
    Parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    Parameter.Value = "Mortgage";

    sds.SelectCommand += "AND LoanType = @LoanType";
    sds.SelectParameters.Add(Parameter);
}
```

Comment: I am using the SQLDataSource in the code behind as well, not on the aspx page. Any advice there?

Comment: OK. I changed the answer. Check the new one