# I'm trying to pass a variable through the URL to SQL to show records for just one result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm trying to pass a variable through the URL with ASP to SQL to show records for just one result.

something like this?

```xml
<asp:SqlDataSource
  ID="dsRecipe"
  runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:theConnectionString %>
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [theTable] WHERE itemNum = "<%# "<%# Request.QueryString["num"] %>"%>"">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, you should be using proper parameterization, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137336/how-to-use-parameterized-queries-in-sqldatasource-selectcommand-in-code-behind

Comment: Sql Injection alert! Bad Idea: follow Charlieface suggestion.